# Show that square matrices $A$, $B$ satisfy $A(A+B)^{-1}B = B(A+B)^{-1}A$ when $A+B$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I got to $B (A^{-1} (A+B))^{-1} =B (A + B)^{-1} A$.

Comment: You don't know if $A$ is invertible though

Comment: @angryavian Does it help if we know $A$ and $B$ are square matrices?

Comment: They have to be square matrices, else $A+B$ isn't square (hence, not invertible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Add $B(A+B)^{-1} B$ to both sides.

Comment: so
$$B=B$$
$$(A+B)(A+B)^{-1}B = B((A+B)^{-1}(A+B))$$
$$A(A+B)^{-1}B + B(A+B)^{-1}B = B(A+B)^{-1}A + B(A+B)^{-1}B$$
$$A(A+B)^{-1}B = B(A+B)^{-1}A$$
is that correct?